# American's opinions on copyright

Tags: united-states, public-opinion, copyright

Have there been any recent surveys with published results on American's opinions on copyright?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Are questions asking for surveys off-topic?

Comment: I've neither downvoted not voted to close, but the reason you are getting downvotes is the lack of research. A search engine found an example of a poll on the public perception of copyright, it is rather old (2004)

Comment: I don't know why this was closed as off topic.  It's poor quality, but it's not off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The general public generally supports the principle of copyright.

https://www.pewresearch.org/internet/2004/12/05/part-4-what-the-general-public-believes/

In that survey from 2004, 43% of people said they were somewhat familiar with copyright law, meaning that over 50% were not familiar.

Moreover, 70% of people said that the life+70 term on copyright was the right length(almost half), or too short.

91% of people thought that making copies of music or movies and selling them to other people should be illegal. And half of all people think that making a copy and giving it to a friend should be illegal (only 1/3 said it should be legal).

15 to 20% of people thought that actions that are generally considered "fair" such as recording a tv show for later viewing or making a photocopy of a page from a book for personal use should be illegal.

Generally then, Americans think copyright laws are about right, or perhaps not strict enough.

Comment: Thank you! I know it's impossible to tell for sure without a more recent poll, but is it likely that opinions have changed since 2004, e.g. due to computers and the Internet being more widely used now than then? Opinions can change a lot in 18 years.

Comment: Anecdotally I don't think opinions have changed substantially. Many people have little understanding of copyright law (I'd say less than 10% of those who claim to be familiar with the law actually *are*).  Many people confuse plagiarism with copyright violation, don't understand the notion of derived work, the distinction between criminal and non-criminal copyright violations or the notion of "fair".  Nevertheless, most people seem to think it is wrong for non-creators to profit from creative works without permission from the creators.